# How to add padding to a plot in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to add padding to the left and the right side of my plot.
But when I change xlim and ylim; the image becomes smaller.

what am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline



df1=df['Total Acc'].round(4)*100 
labels = ['AWA','Rem', 'S1', 'S2', 'SWS', 'SX', 'ALL'] 


rows = [df1.loc[label] for label in labels] 
for row in rows:  
    row.plot(figsize=(10, 5), marker='o')


# http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html ---set_bbox_to_anchor(bbox, transform=None)
myLegend=plt.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.15, 1., .102), prop ={'size':10}, loc=10, ncol=7,  #left, bottom, width, height
                title=r'LEARNING CURVE - Fp1_RF(20)')                                         
myLegend.get_title().set_fontsize('18') 


plt.ylim(97.5, 98.5)
plt.xlim(0, 45) 

plt.xlabel('# of samples per subject')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
```

[image]

Answer (score 23):

If your matplotlib figure is getting trimmed, you can use `Tight Layout`. Details provided [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)

In your code, try adding

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

Another option that you can try is to use `subplots_adjust()`. Basically it provides you control over the default spacing on the left, right, bottom, and top as well as the horizontal and vertical spacing between multiple rows and columns. [Sample Example here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_adjust.html)

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.5, right=0.5)
```

Comment: Neither of them work. The curves start in x=10. and I want the axis to start in 0. That is why I used: plt.xlim(0, 45). It does not work. Meanwhile if I do it for the Y axis (plt.ylim(0, 91); it works.

Comment: Is there a way to simply pad the rendered image with whitespace?

Comment: For more context: I have multiple plots, and without `tight_layout()` they render about the same size but some of the labels get cut off.  With `tight_layout()`, it adjusts the size of the graph to make room for labels when necessary.  I would like to render all graphs at the same size with enough padding to accommodate the largest labels, so it all looks uniform.