# How do I space out the plots on plt.subplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How do I space out the data?

My code:

[image]

The output:

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281851/how-to-add-padding-to-a-plot-in-python ?

Comment: Mostly ```plt.tight_layout()``` does the job.